# Interpreting R nnet Package Multinomial Regression

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, nnet

I need to interpret this summary. I have a response variable with 5 levels (response) and an explanatory variable (taxon) with 2 levels (raptor and others). Can someone help me?

Call:

```
multinom(formula = response ~ taxon, data = data, trace = FALSE)

Coefficients:
          (Intercept) taxonraptor
CA         -1.7045477  -0.2410289
Colission  -1.7045071 -12.1472903
E          -0.4519443  -2.1870233
NR         -3.0912802  -8.2838816
OA        -14.3087225  11.6707716
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to read your results. You need to provide more info about your dependent variable. If you've estimated a multinomial logit model, then you should expect to see 5 parameters:

- 4 constants which capture the effects of being one level relative to the baseline/reference
- 1 effect of "taxon" on the level probability

Now it could also be the case that by default "multinom" estimate level-specific effects for "taxon" - In this case you would have four 4 constants + 4 taxon-related effects.
But again, your results are difficult to read.

Comment: As a side note, this model does not seem very interesting. A simple 2-way contingency table would do the job.